# Will float element's zero height edge be considered as edge?

Tags: css, css-float

According to CSS Specification:

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge
>   touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float.
>   If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned
>   with the top of the current line box.

When I was writing this demo, I found that floats always collapse when height is zero. But I didn't find any declaration about this on CSS Specification. My question is why it behaves like this? Why edge with zero height is not considered an edge?

```css
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:800px;
  background:pink;
}

.f{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
/*   height:50px; */
}

.r{
  position:relative;
}

.a{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='f'>
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class='f'>
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "edge"?

Comment: @Paulie_D edge means the outer edge of float element. "A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float"

Comment: Because an element with no height and no width... *isn't there* for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because it's 0 height so there is no edge and the edge of the containing block will be considered and you will logically have overflow.

Add some animation to better see the effect:

```css
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:800px;
  background:pink;
}

.f{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.r{
  position:relative;
}

.a{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    height:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='f' style="animation:change 3s linear forwards">
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class='f' >
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When reaching 0, we no more have an edge on the first float element so the second one will get shifted to touch the edge of the containing block.

---

The only way to have an edge is to make sure there is at least a small amount of height even if it's a border, padding, etc.

```css
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:800px;
  background:pink;
}

.f{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.r{
  position:relative;
}

.a{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    height:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='f' style="animation:change 3s linear forwards;border-top:0.2px solid">
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class='f' >
    <div class='r'>
      <div class='a'>ITEM2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```